# How to determine AFError from NSError domain and code

Tags: swift, alamofire, nserror

I collected a large amount of errors, however they are logged by conversion to `NSError` domain and code

having these information

```
Domain: Alamofire.AFError
Code: 8
```

how to determine the error

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/AFError.swift

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to `NSError` is a Swift implementation detail, so there's no guaranteed behavior. You should capture them more accurately. However, if you really need it, the current conversion behavior encodes cases with associated values first, then cases without. According to that logic, code 8 would be `requestRetryFailed`. But that determination may change based on Swift version. Best to fix your error logging.